# Как с помощью PHP сделать изображения одинакового размера?

Tags: изображения, php

Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке файлов они превращались в изображения одинакового размера без утраты пропорций?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что в php вы не очень сильны, поэтому используйте для этой задачи [готовые классы](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=resize+image&x=0&y=0&go_search=1). А если посмотрите какой-нибудт из них и разберетесь что к чему, то в следующий раз, без труда, сможете написать свой.

Answer (score 3):

Для уменьшение изображения я делаю так:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmp_img);// получаем размеры картинки
$newwidth=800;
    $pr3=$width/$newwidth; //получаем пропорцию от ширины
    $pr13=$height/$pr3; //делаем высоту по пропорции от ширины
    $normh=$pr13; //высота
    $normw=$newwidth; //ширина
```

Дальше обрезаем фото по новым размерам.

О загрузке файлов почитать: [Скрипт загрузки файлов](http://subcoder.ru/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/)

Как сделать новый размер в изображении читаем:

- [Как изменить размер изображения на PHP? Часть 1: функции](http://shublog.ru/php/kak-izmenit-razmer-izobrazheniya-na-php-chast-1/);
- [Как изменить размер изображения на PHP? Часть 2: Создаём миниатюры](http://shublog.ru/php/kak-izmenit-razmer-izobrazheniya-na-php-chast-2-sozdajom-miniatyury-thumbnails/).

Answer (score -1):

Функция:

```
function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false, $to_gif=0) {
list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
if (!$w_i || !$h_i){ die('Error'); return; }
$types = array('','gif','jpeg','png'); $ext = $types[$type]; if ($ext) {
$func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext; $img = $func($file_input); } else {
die('Error'); return; } if ($percent){ $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
$h_o *= $h_i / 100; } if (!$h_o){ $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i); }
if (!$w_o){ $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i); } $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
if ($type == 2) {
if($to_gif){ return imagegif($img_o,$file_output); }
else return imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
} else { $func = 'image'.$ext; return $func($img_o,$file_output); } }
```

Использование:

```
resize($old_file, $new_file, $w, $h, false, false);
```

Comment: @Антон Малюта, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Жесть... die() в теле функции без реальной на то необходимости... Страшный код...